# How to select a specific node from XDocument having a specific attribute value?

Tags: c#, xml

Here is my xml,

```
<root>
 <A>
    <B  id="ABC">one
    </B>
    <B id="ZYZ">two
    </B>
    <B  id="QWE">three
    </B>
    <B>four
    </B>
  </A>
</root>
```

using following **c#** code to fetch only the node `<B id="QWE">three</B>` ,

```
var x = xdoc.Descendants("B").Where(ele => ele.Attribute("id").Value.Equals("QWE"));
```

but variable `x` is always null, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your xml example, not all `B` nodes have `id` attribute. `Attribute("id")` will return null for that nodes and when you access `Value` on null, you get a `NullReferenceException`.

Use next code to avoid that error:

```
var x = xdoc.Descendants("B")
            .Where(ele => (string)ele.Attribute("id") == "QWE");
```

`Attribute` method returns `XElement`. When you cast it to `string` , it takes the string representation of that element, in our case that would be the value of an attribute (you can see more details on casting [XElement to string at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263.aspx)). Now, when `Attribute` returns null, casting it to string would give a null. `==` Operator will always return false for null and `"QWE"` literal, no exception will be thrown.

If, for some reason, you don't want to cast `XElement` to `string`, you can use [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) to see if `id` attribute is present for `ele` node (code becomes less readable quite quickly).

```
var x = xdoc.Descendants("B")
            .Where(ele => (ele.Attribute("id") != null ? ele.Attribute("id").Value : null) == "QWE");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not XPath?

```
var x = xdoc.XPathSelectElement("//B[@id='QWE']")
```